# Calling External API(ERP Application) in Sharepoint aspx page

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-integration

I would like to call an external API from Sharepoint aspx page using any method like server side or client side.Is there any approach for doing this.

If yes please refer some links with some examples.

In my case external API would be ERP applications like SAP.

I am just trying to get the user information in my sharepoint page using below link but could not achieve that.
[Building Custom API for SharePoint online](https://blogs.msmvps.com/windsor/2017/03/12/walkthrough-building-a-custom-web-api-for-use-with-sharepoint-online/)

Expecting an early reply.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This can be done a few different ways.

Since you are trying to get information from the SAP application to SharePoint, you can use web services.  Transactions such as REST might be the way.  Also if you have access to the SAP endpoint, BDC would be the way to do it.

Underlying the BDC is a WCF service.  Predominantly a C# framework, but can talk to other endpoints in a variety of ways, including REST.

What information are you trying to get into SharePoint?

If you're going client side, then the JavaScript you write will have to make calls against the SAP API and the CSOM.  There's also a client side way of talking to SharePoint strictly with making REST calls.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Actually i am yet to receive the external application details and it may be SAP or ORACLE anything. Now am trying to consume the API in our sharepoint aspx page using client side methods. So If possible could you give some example methods with sample code.I have tried to use quickbase API for POC. Now am able to get the ticket in my sharepoint page using javascript.So to proceed with that ticket i need to us some API in quickbase.Any example code will be helpful.

Comment: Here's a link talking about quickbase with some sample code...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29386945/how-can-i-retrieve-add-data-using-quickbase-api-and-javascript

Comment: Whenever tackling these kinds of problems I find it easier when I diagram it out...I usually use Visio but a simple doodle also goes a long way too...especially when you're trying to talk between two disparate systems